# Custom CSS Sidebar Shop Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

could you help with a css for currency i want currency to like same like price please help https://snipboard.io/q9uTQe.jpg  and would you please help for the css https://snipboard.io/8Uo4Mg.jpg for this as i am not able to get a css for size above and colors below , im really strugling with it

Comment: Could you brief it more? Are you trying to swap the position of size and colors? Are you trying to make price and currency fonts same?

Comment: @SurajSanwal yes im trying to swap the position of size and colors and trying to make price font same to  currency font

Comment: For making currency font as same as price you need to override the default CSS Try the CSS that is in my next comment and let me know it works or not.

For swapping position of size and colors m not sure it will be doable using Css or not but you can play with html structure in child theme of your current theme. Else js will be an other option to do the same.

Comment: .main-archive-product h4>sup {
      font-size: 13px !important;
      font-weight: 600 !important;
    }

Comment: yes the font thing worked tysm for that but i still dont know how to do the 2nd part please helpp this will mean a lot

Comment: Which theme you are using?

Comment: funio https://preview.themeforest.net/item/funio-funiture-woocommerce-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/29912672?_ga=2.221170459.240696368.1666168561-883480649.1654370804&_gac=1.152651467.1666168561.CjwKCAjwwL6aBhBlEiwADycBIFTFycn7t2zb0P4CyJLm2KpFP893En6YMjdHr99ksgD2MkEKuaUkOxoCGpAQAvD_BwE

Comment: Alright! lemme try if I can made this working using CSS only. Else you need to use have to use javascript in case you are not using child theme.

Comment: Shah I have added an answer to your question please check below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For making the currency font as same as the price you need to override the default CSS Try the CSS given below and let me know if it works or not.

```
.main-archive-product h4>sup { 
  font-size: 13px !important;
  font-weight: 600 !important;
 }
```

For swapping the position of size and colors try to add the below custom CSS.
Note: In case it's not working please try to make these CSS properties important.

```
.bwp-filter-ajax #bwp_form_filter_product {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.bwp-filter-ajax #bwp_form_filter_product .bwp-filter-price {
  order: 1;
}

.bwp-filter-ajax #bwp_form_filter_product .bwp-filter-size {
 order: 2;
}

.bwp-filter-ajax #bwp_form_filter_product .bwp-filter-color {
  order: 3;
}
```

Let me know if it helps or not!

Answer (score 0):

```
`.bwp-filter-ajax #bwp_form_filter_product .bwp-filter-price {
  order: 1 !important;
  order: 2 !important;
  order: 3 !important;
  }`
```

hey this one worked tysmm sir siraj

Comment: Happy to hear that your query is resolved. You're welcome :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).